# Does Ativan / lorazepam ever cause unconsciousness, or only memory loss?

Tags: memory, consciousness

An Ativan injection, probably 20-min after the event, erased my memory starting 30-min *prior* to the event until (maybe 1-hour or so?) after the event. Because of memory loss, the injuries were the only reason I know something happened to me.

Initially, I'd just described myself as having been "unconscious" to explain my 100% lack of memories. CLEARLY though, as I think about "what just happened to me???", *consciousness* as an explanation for loss of memory prior to the event is ridiculous.

Ativan / Lorazepam clearly wiped my memory starting 50-min prior to the injection, and then after the injection the transport to ER, ER xrays, a blood test, and stitches to my face.

So... was it likely I was ever **conscious** during that extended memory loss period. Maybe talking to the EMTs? Able to describe the event, before the injected Ativan overwhelmed me and erased my memory?

Is that how it works? I was interacting with EMTS and ER people then, "zap" my memory was erased?
**OR**
The Ativan injection made me so passive, I was unaware of my surroundings and Ativan also blocked memories from forming (however that happens in the brain). I was in an ambulance. I was getting xrays. I was getting stitches. The stitches were 4 on my face, so Ativan was either a pain killer or they gave me something.

*This is important* , during my memory loss period, is it possible I was talking and making decisions?

Comment: There could be answerable questions in here, but as presented it is way too wrapped up in your personal case. This needs to be something between you and your doctors.